# Run sen2cor process on Earth Engine API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, sen2cor

I want run the sen2cor process, with the L2A_Process executable, for transform the Sentinel-2 L1C product in L2A but I need this on the earth engine platform. I'm using the Earth Engine Python API on Datalab but I don't understand how I can run the sen2cor executable on this platform.

Comment: Where did you get data? Because Sen2cor needs a lot of metadata to apply correction and uploaded scenes on GGE contains only layers plus a few metadata

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Datalab is available as a Docker container, and you can add libraries to this container by following instructions in the Datalab documentation [Adding Python libraries to a Cloud Datalab instance](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries#adding_python_libraries_to_a_cloud_datalab_instance) page. Using this approach you can install the Sen2Cor libraries, as described in Section 4.4 of the [Sen2Cor Software
Release Note](http://step.esa.int/thirdparties/sen2cor/2.4.0/Sen2Cor_240_Documenation_PDF/S2-PDGS-MPC-L2A-SRN-V2.4.0.pdf).

If you are not familiar with customizing Docker containers, see Docker's [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Comment: I try the instruction in the Datalab documentatio fo adding python libraries but when I try the command "!pip install sen2cor" I obtain an error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sen2cor (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sen2cor.

Comment: I try create a container with the .tar file for install sen2cor (standalone) inside, then in datalab I install it with the command: "%%bash python /folder_sen2cor/setup.py install" and it seems work. Now if I use "!pip install sen2cor" the output is "Requirement already satisfied: sen2cor in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sen2cor-2.4.0-py2.7.egg" so I think it work. The problem now is that if i start the L2A_Process I obtain an error "No module named lxml.etree" but if I try "!pip install lxml.etree" the output is  "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml.etree..."

Answer (score 1):

Finally I can start the L2A_Process but it need other packages like tables, lxml... I was able to install these packages with the !pip command but when I try it for the gdal package I obtain this error:

[image]